# AWS Postgres: Copy data from one account to another

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 2 AWS accounts which runs the Postgres DB. These two accounts have the same schemas/same tables. I want to copy all the data from Account 1 to Account 2. At the end, Account 2 will have its previous data + Account 1's data copied over. To do this, I shared the snapshot from Account 1 to Account 2. Logged into Account 2 and got the Account 1's snapshot.

Now, How to get the data from Account 1 snapshot and update existing tables in Account 2.  Is there a easy way to do this?